# HTTP headers "q" factor in firefox?

Tags: firefox, http-headers

Does anyone know what the "q" factor HTTP headers emitted by Firefox 3 mean?

It only appears in the Accept and Accept-Charset headers.

For example:

**Accept**: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;**q=0.9**,****/****;**q=0.8**

**Accept-Charset**: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;**q=0.7**,*;**q=0.7**

I've tried trawling the web but I haven't quite found the answer.

Is it some sort of weighting, heuristic value or something to do with localization?

Thanks,

Phil'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) should clarify the "q" parameter, which comes from "quality factor".

> Quality factors allow the user or user
>   agent to indicate the relative degree
>   of preference for that media-range,
>   using the qvalue scale from 0 to 1.
>   The default value is q=1.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.9

HTTP content negotiation (section 12) uses short "floating point" numbers to indicate the relative importance ("weight") of various negotiable parameters. A weight is normalized to a real number in the range 0 through 1, where 0 is the minimum and 1 the maximum value. If a parameter has a quality value of 0, then content with this parameter is `not acceptable' for the client. HTTP/1.1 applications MUST NOT generate more than three digits after the decimal point. User configuration of these values SHOULD also be limited in this fashion.

"Quality values" is a misnomer, since these values merely represent relative degradation in desired quality.